# How to save model in spacy for custom NER which is again trainable?

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

Let's say I have trained my model with label called "FRUIT" and saved it using `nlp.to_disk("F:/Saved Models/FRUIT_pipeline")`

Now if I load this model and train again for label called "SEASON", all my before training is lost. How do I save it for multiple labels in multiple training?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the FAQ entries on catastrophic forgetting](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226#:%7E:text=my%20retrained%20model%20forgot%20pretrained%20entities).

Basically, the easiest workaround is to train your model on all your training data at once. There are other methods to avoid forgetting but they are experimental.